# pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-efs, persistent-volume-claims, storage-class-specifier

I am trying to install elastic cluster on k8s using helm. k8s cluster is running on AWS ec2 nodes. 1 master and 3 workers.

Getting pod error:

```
  Warning  FailedScheduling  59m   default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..

  Warning  FailedMount       41m   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-f3f29bff-2b1b-4dbd-9446-dd3dccb24bc3" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "fs-0253b6017a85b027f:/" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/10c03d1e-4fa9-4515-98ce-7c4a4cf89ce9/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-f3f29bff-2b1b-4dbd-9446-dd3dccb24bc3/mount": mount failed: exit status 32
```

Helm Config:

```
# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "512M"

# To allocate more space if above requests and limits aren't enough
# resources:
  # requests:
    # cpu: "500m"
    # memory: "2Gi"
  # limits:
    # cpu: "1000m"
    # memory: "5G"

# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "efs-sc"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
```

Pod State:

```
elasticsearch-master-0                      0/1     Init:0/1           0               56m
elasticsearch-master-1                      0/1     Init:0/1           0               56m
elasticsearch-master-2                      0/1     Init:0/1           0               56m
```

PVC created:

```
NAME                                          STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   Bound    pvc-f3f29bff-2b1b-4dbd-9446-dd3dccb24bc3   100M       RWO            efs-sc         57m
elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1   Bound    pvc-c1e65b23-059f-4a79-9421-90f0128774ea   100M       RWO            efs-sc         57m
elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   Bound    pvc-605ce795-a97e-458a-aa89-8d29537eee76   100M       RWO            efs-sc         57m
```

PV created:

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                                 STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-605ce795-a97e-458a-aa89-8d29537eee76   100M       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   efs-sc                  57m
pvc-c1e65b23-059f-4a79-9421-90f0128774ea   100M       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1   efs-sc                  57m
pvc-f3f29bff-2b1b-4dbd-9446-dd3dccb24bc3   100M       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   efs-sc
```

Storage Class:

```
NAME     PROVISIONER       RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
efs-sc   efs.csi.aws.com   Delete          Immediate           false                  24h
```

CSI Driver:

```
NAME              ATTACHREQUIRED   PODINFOONMOUNT   STORAGECAPACITY   TOKENREQUESTS   REQUIRESREPUBLISH   MODES        AGE
efs.csi.aws.com   false            false            false             <unset>         false               Persistent   28h
```

Not finding the reason why pod is not able to mount.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the CSI controller? Could be permission issues with the EFS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In worker node's security group,  inbound nfs rule had to be added. After adding that , it works fine.